# Issues with extracting css files in angular and Chrome DevTools

Tags: css, angular, google-chrome, webpack

I use `ng serve -sm -ec` to extract scss file in `angular 5`, but when i make changes in `Elements` onglet of `Chrome DevTools` like that

[image]

it didn't save automatically

[image]

I have to change it in `Sources` onglet and save it to make it work.

1. How can i make changes directly in the `Elements` onglet ?
2. How to prevent angular from reloading the page and creating bundles again each time i change scss files ?